# Infix function in Kotlin DSL does not work without this keyword in parent context

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-dsl

I am writing a sample DSL to create an infra-as-code library. The basic structure would be as below:

```
class Employee internal constructor (private val init: Employee.() -> Unit) {
    var name:String = ""
    var address:String = ""

    infix fun showMessage(msg:String) =
        println("${this.name} resides at ${this.address} and wishes you $msg")

    internal fun describe(){
        init()
        //initialization
    }
}

fun employee(process:Employee.()->Unit) = Employee(process).describe()

fun main(){

    employee {
        name="John Doe"
        address="Amsterdam"
        this showMessage "happy new year"
       // showMessage("This works")
    }

}
```

I am thinking that showMessage infix function should work as other infix inside the Employee context but i need to use `this` to make it work as an infix.
The function invocation works well in the context without this.
Is this the behaviour of infix functions while using along with DSL or am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working as designed. From the [docs on infix functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#infix-notation):

> Note that infix functions always require both the receiver and the parameter to be specified. When you're calling a method on the current receiver using the infix notation, use this explicitly. This is required to ensure unambiguous parsing.